# How to access "this" from an anonymous function in an extension function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to write an extension function for LiveData, where onChanged only gets called once, and then the observer gets removed.

```
@MainThread
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    this.observe(owner, Observer {
        observer.onChanged(it)
        this.removeObserver(this)
    })
}
```

This code won't compile, because the keyword "this" refers to the LiveData object in this function extension. Instead I want to refer to the observer, to remove it. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a lambda for that, you have to do it like this

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    this.observe(owner, object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```